# Complexity of recognizing generalized graph join

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, cc-complexity-theory

A [join](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphJoin.html) of two graphs is the union of both graphs with additional edges such that every vertex of the first graph is connected to every vertex of the second graph. There is a generalization of this, which I will call the $G$-join. For a given graphs $G$ and $G_1, G_2 \cdots G_{v}$, where $v$ is the number of vertices in $G$, the $G$-join of the graphs is the union of all of them such that every vertex of $G_u$ is connected to every vertex of $G_v$ if there is an edge between $u$ and $v$ in $G$. So the original graph join is just a $P_2$-join.

How fast can we recognize whatever a graph is $G$-join? What if we fix $G$ to a specific graph?

The only algorithm I could think of is the obvious one, iterate over all partitions and check the edges.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_decomposition